# And vs or for a plural noun

Tags: grammar, construction, and-or

Situation: there are ten students in my room. Some of them have blue books. Some others have red ones. Now, I am telling my subordinate to instruct them all to study the notes in the corresponding books. Which one should I say?

A. Please inform the students with the red books **and** blue books that they need to understand the notes in the books before the exam.

B. Please inform the students with the red books **or** blue books that they need to understand the notes in the books before the exam.

AND or OR?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Plurality has no bearing on whether to use "and" or "or."  If you want both sets of students informed, you'd say, "Please inform the students with the red books and the students with the blue books that they need to understand the notes in their books before the exam."  If the books are the same, though, but just different colors, I wouldn't go into all that.  I'd just say, "Please inform the students that they need to understand the notes in their books before the exam."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Okay. What about the following: There is a squad of servicemen who will engage in a mission. Each of them is allowed to take along a knife or a sword, not both. Which one should I use: You should take along knives (and/or) axes with you.

Comment: In answer to you comment here: you shouldn't use any of these; the sentence structure *You should take along NOUN with you* comes out really odd. An idiomatic and grammatical way of saying what you want to say would be *You should bring either a knife or a sword*

Comment: @Hannah I mean, the knives and swords are right before them, on a table. Each of them is allowed to take either a knife or a sword to the mission.

Comment: Right. Then perhaps *You should pick either a knife or a sword* would be better? Yet another alternative might be *you're allowed to take either a knife or a sword with you*

Comment: @Hannah But, I am talking to a number of servicemen, so, don't you think I should regard "you" as a plural pronoun here? Therefore, I should use "knives and swords"?

Comment: Mm, I see your point... but fact is that it will be ambiguous either way, because if you use the plural, that could still be interpreted as several knives or swords each. To avoid this, you could have *you're allowed to take one knife or one sword each with you*

Comment: @Hannah thanks for getting my point. It's satisfying, really. I have upvoted your comment. Thanks for the answer as well, hannah :)

Comment: You're welcome :) And thanks for the upvote :)